# Split a value and units in Ruby

Tags: ruby

What is the most elegant way to split a value and units, so you have:

```
13min.some_method["value"] = 13
13min.some_method["unit"] = "min"
```

I think it should use unpack or split, but I can get it to work!

Comment: Using `to_f` is something to consider if you need to parse more than just whole numbers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000812):

```
>> "13min".scan(/\d+|[^\d]+/)
=> ["13", "min"]
```

Another way:

```
>> i = "13min" =~ /[^\d]/
=> 2
>> "13min"[0,i]
=> "13"
>> "13min"[i,"13min".length]
=> "min"
```

The reason String#split isn't the best is because it gets rid of the delimiter, but your two strings are butted up against each other.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative you could try (which will also work with floats and negative numbers):

```
s = "-123.45min"

value = s.to_f          # => -123.45
unit = s[/[a-zA-Z]+/]   # => "min"
```

Like Ruby's `to_f` and `to_i` method, it will just "try" to get a result. So if you don't provide a unit, `unit` will be `nil` - if you only provide a unit, value will be 0.

```
"123-34min"    value = 123,     unit = "min"
"min"          value = 0        unit = "min"
"-1234"        value = -1234    unit = nil
"123-foo-bar"  value = 123      unit = "foo"
```

P.S. Of course this assumes that you don't have any numbers in your unit.